# counting the rows using group_by of two other columns in r

Tags: r, group-by

I have data as below. I would like to add a new column that counts whenever column `code` changes and when `ID` changes it resets and counter to 1 and start counting.

```
ID  code   
1    10     
1    10     
1    11     
1    11     
1    21     
1    21     
2    10     
2    10     
2    11     
2    11     
2    11     
2    14     
2    15
```

result:

```
ID  code   counter
1    10     1
1    10     1
1    11     2
1    11     2
1    21     3
1    21     3
2    10     1
2    10     1
2    11     2
2    11     2
2    11     2
2    14     3
2    15     4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may use `cumsum` along with `duplicated` as in

```
df %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(counter = cumsum(!duplicated(code)))
# A tibble: 13 x 3
# Groups:   ID [2]
#       ID  code counter
#    <int> <int>   <int>
#  1     1    10       1
#  2     1    10       1
#  3     1    11       2
#  4     1    11       2
#  5     1    21       3
#  6     1    21       3
#  7     2    10       1
#  8     2    10       1
#  9     2    11       2
# 10     2    11       2
# 11     2    11       2
# 12     2    14       3
# 13     2    15       4
```

If `code` reverted back, say, from 11 to 10, then `counter` wouldn't increase. But I guess either that's not possible in your case or that would even be the desired effect.

Here's how `duplicated` works in this case:

```
cbind(df[df$ID == 1, "code"], !duplicated(df[df$ID == 1, "code"]))
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]   10    1
# [2,]   10    0
# [3,]   11    1
# [4,]   11    0
# [5,]   21    1
# [6,]   21    0
```

Whenever a new value in `code` appears, it gives a one, and then `cumsum` finishes the job.

Comment: just curious, what would be the data.table syntax to do this?

Comment: @YOLO, looks like `DT[, counter := cumsum(!duplicated(code)), by = .(ID)]`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `dplyr`, using `lag` to find rows where `code` changes:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
    group_by(ID) %>% 
    mutate(counter = cumsum(c(1, tail(code != lag(code), -1))))
```

Result:

```
      ID  code counter
   <int> <int>   <dbl>
 1     1    10       1
 2     1    10       1
 3     1    11       2
 4     1    11       2
 5     1    21       3
 6     1    21       3
 7     2    10       1
 8     2    10       1
 9     2    11       2
10     2    11       2
11     2    11       2
12     2    14       3
13     2    15       4
```